# Getting list of layers when opening a QGIS project on a standalone app?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, pyqgis-3, standalone, layout-manager

I am trying to make a standalone QGIS app to read a .qgs file for rendering an image based on the vectors using LayoutManager.
The problem is that when I try to print `project.mapLayers()` I get an empty dictionary

I don't know if it is the best method to do this.

There is my code:

```py
import os

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qt5\plugins'  
os.environ['PATH'] += r';C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qt5\bin'  

from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
prj = project.read(r'C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\Standalone\Livrable TW\P2.qgs')
print(project)
print(prj)

######################
print(project.mapLayers())
layers = project.mapLayers()
######################

manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = 'Layout1'
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
# remove any duplicate layouts
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

# create map item in the layout
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.setRect(10,10,10,10)

# set the map extent
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers(layers)
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.0)
ms.setExtent(rect)
map.setExtent(rect)
map.setScale(750*18)
map.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255,255,255,0))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)

map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(180, 180, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
#legend.setTitle("Legend")
layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
for layer in layers:
    layerTree.addLayer(layer)
legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(200, 5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

scalebar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
scalebar.setStyle('Single Box')
scalebar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceMeters)
scalebar.setNumberOfSegments(4)
scalebar.setNumberOfSegmentsLeft(0)
scalebar.setUnitsPerSegment(100)
scalebar.setLinkedMap(map)
scalebar.setUnitLabel('m')
# scalebar.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14)) # <--- Deprecated
scalebar.update()
layout.addLayoutItem(scalebar)
scalebar.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(20, 190, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

title = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
title.setText('My Title')
title.setFont(QFont('Arial', 24))
title.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(title)
title.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutName)
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)

fn = 'C:/temp/layout_export.png'
exporter.exportToImage(fn, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())


qgs.exitQgis()
```

Edit:
Edit: I complete my question because I have continued searching a solution. My problem seems that it could came from the prefix who may not be correctly defined because when I try to import vector layers and verifying if the layer correctly imported with

```py
vlayer.isValid()
```

it returns

```py
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution to my problem.
It was about my batch file who init the program.

It finally work using this to call my program:

```
ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
set QGISHOME=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\
rem set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH% 
rem set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

@echo off 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat" 
@echo off 
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass76\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass76\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
rem "%PYTHONHOME%\python" %*

cd /d %~dp0

start cmd
```

It seems that I wasn't setting up the good environement variables.